# How can I save an distorted image in the map_func of map_and_batch in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to save the an image into a file.jpg after it's distorted to see the difference in TensorFlow benchmark project. Now I do this job as below, in preprocessing.py I add these codes here after distort_color func

```
distorted_image = distort_color(distorted_image, batch_position, distort_color_in_yiq=distort_color_in_yiq)
distorted_image_tmp = tf.cast(distorted_image, dtype=tf.uint8)
image_tmp = tf.image.encode_jpeg(distorted_image)
out = tf.write_file("image_tmp_" + str(index) + ".jpg", image_tmp)
tf.add_to_collection('out', out)
```

Then I add these in benchmark_cnn.py file after done batches benchmark step

```
print(tf.get_collection('out'))
sess.run(tf.get_colleciton('out'))
```

After I run the modified benchmark over, the first print func outputs '[]', and no image_tmp_xxx.jpg saved under the execution path.

I try to not insert the add_to_collection and get_collection lines, and the benchmark runs into NameError

```
NameError: global name 'out' is not defined
```

I think it's because the tensor 'out' is defined in preprocessing.py but not in benchmark_cnn.py, but I don't know how to export it into benchmark_cnn.py so I use add_to_collection and get_collection function to do this. Is it right to use add_to_collection and get_collection function like this?

If it's right, how can I save the file successfully in the 
map_func, namely parse_and_preprocess exactly?

Comment: the benchmark project I mentioned is downloaded from here https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks